# Reconstructing a vector field on the circle

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems

Consider a ODE on the circle of the form
\begin{align*}
  \frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \omega(x) \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $\omega(x) > 0$. The "speed" $\omega$ along the circle is not known and the only observation available is the evolution of a density function $p : S^1 \to \mathbb R$ with the given flow of the ODE.

I was wondering if this, or something similar to this, might be a well-known problem. I could not formulate a result and would be thankful for any hints.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ? Do you want some analytical solution or looking for numerical approaches ?

Comment: The density as a function of time $p(x,t)$ satisfies a transport equation, which should let you recover $\omega$ as long as the gradient of $p(x,0)$ is non-zero somewhere and $\omega doesn't vanish.

Comment: @PiyushGrover: yes I was looking for some analytical solution first.

Comment: @D. Thomine: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking of looking at the ODE in arc length coordinates which reduces to an advection on say $[0,1]$ where the left and right ends are identified as the same point. But the advection equation yields an equation that involves derivatives of $\omega$ as well. I m not sure if you can always solve for $\omega$ under the conditions that you gave.

Comment: My bad. You get a transport equation, but that assumes that you first renormalise by the invariant density, which you can do... if you already know the vector field.

Comment: Otherwise, writing $r (x,t) := \ln (p) (x,t)$, you get an ODE on $\omega'$, which is $\partial_t r = \omega (\omega'-\partial_x r)$ In general, I guess that isn't integrable. Note that if you find a time $t_0$ such that $\partial_t p (x,t_0) = 0$, then $\omega' (x) = \partial_x r (x,t_0)$ (in other words, follow the summit of the wave), and you can get $\omega (x)$ from there. I don't know about the robustness of the method, though.